# why is link generated in YUI javascript failing to render in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yui, yahoo-widgets

Using YAHOO.widget.treeview to generate a table with three levels of data: module, submodule, and detail.   If there is an image associated with a detail row the javascript generates a link:

```
"<td><a href=\"/screenshot/show/" + rowData.id + "\">Screenshot</a></td>"
```

that is appended to the html for the row.

The url is generated correctly and the link appears.   When clicked nothing happens except the word 'Done' appears in the browser status bar.

Am calling the very same url from another page that does not use javascript and the screenshot page appears as expected.

Here is the controller.

class ScreenshotController < ApplicationController
  def show
      if @detail.screen_path.length > 1
    @imagePath = "#{RAILS_ROOT}" +
      "/private/#{Company.find(@detail.company_id).subdir}/" +
      "#{Project.find(@detail.project_id).subdir}/screenshot/" +
      "#{@detail.screen_path}"
       send_file ( @imagePath, :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'inline')
    end
  end
end

A sample url:  http://localhost:3004/screenshot/show/20854

This code from show.html.erb belonging to the detail model works:

View', :controller => 'screenshot', :id => @detail.id, :action => 'show' %>

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

maybe there's some unwanted js that intercepts your click on generated links?